# Left-align header to right border of <ul>

Tags: html, css, flask, jinja2, frontend

I am writing a flask app, and have run into a bit of an issue... As you can see from this picture:[image: python-explorer]

I have a slightly offset header (Python Explorer v0.0.1) and want to make it so that the offset is aligned with the right border of the gray list, so that it looks like:[image: python explorer]

I would just leave it like that, but the length of the list is variable (flask generates what will be in the list before rendering the page) length, so I'm not sure how to structure the css. Here is the jinja2 template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <title>Python-Explorer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/pyexp.css') }}">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1 id="header_name">Python Explorer v{{ peversion }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="python_list">
            <ul>
            {%- for ver in versions %}
                <li><a href="#" class="glow">{{ ver }}</a></li>
            {%- endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    height: 40px;
    background: black;
}

#header_name {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 150px;
    color: white;
}

.python_list ul {
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    border: solid gray 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: gray;
}

.python_list ul li {
    padding: 3px;
}


a.glow, a.glow:hover, a.glow:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
    -o-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
    transition: 500ms linear 0s;
    outline: 0 none;
}

a.glow:hover, a.glow:focus
{
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ffc, 1px -1px 8px #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per additional details provided over IRC, I've made it so the python_list does not use a traditional sidebar with a percentage width nor fixed width. This pen accomplishes what you need.

The main thing I did is move the header_name and the python_list into the same div. Then I added a padding equivalent to the height of the header bar which is 40px to the top of the python_list. This allows the list to drop down below the bar but still maintain its width for the purposes of spacing out the "Python Explorer" title string. Along with that, display: inline-block was used to align both of those two divs side by side.

Hopes this helps!

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <title>Python-Explorer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/pyexp.css') }}">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="python_list">
                <ul>
                    {%- for ver in versions %}
                        <li><a href="#" class="glow">{{ ver }}</a></li>
                    {%- endfor %}
                </ul>
                <div id="header_name">
                    <h1>Python Explorer v{{ peversion }}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

CSS:
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.header {
position: relative;
height: 40px;
background: black;
}

#header_name {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
}
#header_name h1 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.python_list {
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 40px;
}
.python_list ul {
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px;
border: solid gray 1px;
display: inline-block;
background: gray;
}

.python_list ul li {
padding: 3px;
}


a.glow, a.glow:hover, a.glow:focus {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
text-shadow: none;
-webkit-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
-moz-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
-o-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
transition: 500ms linear 0s;
outline: 0 none;
}

a.glow:hover, a.glow:focus
{
color: white;
text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ffc, 1px -1px 8px #fff;
}
```

[See the demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjyYeJ)